# Two application with android:process being set to the same, what is the memory limitation?

Tags: android

I have two application with android:process being set to the same value because I want some simple data sharing; If one independent app's memory limit is 20MB, what is the limitation for the two apps? 20MB for two as a whole or 20MB for each the same as independent app?